# Difficulty Importing "sympy"

Tags: sympy

I am trying to import sympy in Spyder 5.2.2 using:
'from sympy import *'

This worked a couple of days ago, but now I am getting an error on the import:
"name 'init_printing' is not defined"

Does anyone else have this issue or know of a solution?

Comment: Which Sympy version?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and importing it as something worked out.
You can try:

```
import sympy as sp

from sympy import init_printing

init_printing()

from sympy import init_session
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the import error right away on "import sympy as sp'